# How to check Google Cloud credit code expiration day?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have received Google Cloud redeem code which would give me $200 a month for next year. Is there a way to check its expiration day? Can I wait and redeem it eg. in a year or do I have to redeem it right away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of credit codes received in developer community program, they have to be redeemed in 60 days after receiving them. Expiration date of the credit itself is one year from the moment of applying them to the account. Expiration date can be checked on https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/redeem
 but it will always show a date in exactly one year, which can be a little misleading - this date doesn’t show the date until when you have time to redeem the code.

Source: https://developers.google.com/actions/community/faq#google_cloud_credit

Google can also cancel your credit if you won’t use 50% of it within 3 months - see terms and conditions here: https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/redeem/terms

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't upgraded your account yet (i.e. you're still in trial mode, and not paying mode) then you should be able to just enter the code to redeem, and you'll get a popup asking you to upgrade your account before you can redeem the credits. On that page where it tells you to upgrade, there will be a line that tells you when the credits expire.

I haven't done this myself, but found this:

https://itnext.io/redeem-and-use-google-cloud-platform-credit-before-it-expires-f1c0151b5016

Comment: The form on https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/redeem now looks a little different. I can confirm that there is additional step before redeeming the code that shows expiration date. It also turned out that it's a code for one month and I should receive another codes for next 11 months.